# Unable to create table using pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g, relational-database

```
declare
type yy is table of t12.name%type index by binary_integer;
y yy;
n number:=1;
begin
execute immediate 'create table rat1 ( name varchar2(10) )';
commit;

select name bulk collect into y from t12;
for i in (select id,name from t12)
loop
dbms_output.put_line(y(n));
n:=n+1;
end loop;
forall i in y.first..y.last
insert into rat1 values(y(i));
end;
```

Its giving `ora-00942`.
I checked about it...at some website it was mentioning that you have to give following privilages...

```
grant select on sys.v_$paramenter to abc
```

I am unable to do that also..Can any body help me with this

Comment: Plus..I dont want to use any concept of procedures or cursors here.....

Comment: Note that executing DDL in PL/SQL with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is not a good idea. You should do that in an SQL script, independent from the PL/SQL code. PL/SQL is not intended to create tables and the likes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

change it so that it is executed in 2 successive steps (NOT in one PL/SQL anonymous block like it is now):

First this

```
begin
execute immediate 'create table rat1 ( name varchar2(10) )';
commit;
end;
```

THEN as a SECOND block this

```
declare
type yy is table of t12.name%type index by binary_integer;
y yy;
n number:=1;
begin

select name bulk collect into y from t12;
for i in (select id,name from t12)
loop
dbms_output.put_line(y(n));
n:=n+1;
end loop;
forall i in y.first..y.last
insert into rat1 values(y(i));
end;
```

**EDIT - as per comment:**

Before execution the WHOLE PL/SQL block is parsed - all objects used in an PL/SQL block must exist BEFORE the PL/SQL block is executed...

Comment: Thanx....if i understand it right..then.
Any DDl does not come into effect till 1 block of pl/sql is executed succesfully

Comment: GOAL: Nothing much I m just on the way of learning PL/SQL..so was just doing experiments..trials and errors....

Comment: no - it comes into effect but before execution the whole PL/SQL block is parsed - so all objects used in an PL/SQL block must exist BEFORE the PL/SQL block is executed... please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help...

Comment: But I am still not able to do it....i tried it to do it in nested begin but it still showed that table doesnt exist..

Comment: Do I have to do it in separate sql files..and then execute it one by one..coz that would be the obv way..i m trying to do it in same file

Comment: I receive `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:`.

Answer (score 3):

You should do it in two separate blocks.

First block:

```
begin
...
end;
/
```

The slash indicates that your buffer should be sent to the DBMS and evaluated. It indicates where your PL/SQL code ends and evaluation can begin.

Then the next:

```
declare
...
begin
...
end;
/
```

Thus, you have:

```
begin
...
end;
/
declare
...
begin
...
end;
/
```

It works under SQL*Plus and SQLDeveloper.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I receive `ORA-06550: line 277, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN`. Moreover, when I enter the slash I get a syntax error. I use SQLDeveloper.

Comment: Please note that the ellipsis `...` must be changed into actual working code.

Comment: Yes I figured that out.

Comment: Then you need to post a question with the code that has the problem. We need more information.

Comment: Thanks @LudovicKuty I will.

Comment: You can add a comment here when it is done. That way I will be able to try to answer to your question

Answer (score 2):

If working withing within SQLPlus block, all DDL changes mus be performed with *execute immediate*. 
Unfortunately, those changes are invisible until block finishes execution.

To work around this problem, please use consequently *execute immediate* for all following statements that depends on former "hidden" changes. That applies also for DML statements. In your case:

```
...
execute immediate 'insert into rat1 values('||y(i)||')';
...
```